# How to return filter chain (chain.filter(exchange)) on webclient request success in spring cloud gateway's filter in Microservices

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-webclient

What I am doing?
Answer: I am creating  microservices using Spring Cloud, I have created a Spring Cloud gateway which sits in front of all my services. In this Spring Cloud Gateway I have a filter which intercepts all the requests and sends the request to another AUTH-SERVICE for authentication and authorization through `WebClient`, based on the HTTP status:

- 200: Now the auth/authorization has done forward request to another microservices, let's say USER-MICROSERVICES
- AnyOtherCode:  Return the Response

Problem I am Facing?
Answer: I am facing two problems, as I am very new to reactive programing and webclient:

1. When I receive `success` from AUTH-SERVICE, I am unable to do `return chain.filter(exchange)` properly in webclient and the request is not going to USER-SERVICE, instead it just returns `success` with `200` status code.
2. When auth failed, with debugging I can see the proper response code `403` in webclient but while returning it's showing `500`.

So basically I am not able to write `WebClient` properly.

```java
@Component
public class JwtFilter implements GatewayFilter  {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private RouterValidator routerValidator;

    @Resource
    private WebClient webClient;


    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();

        if (routerValidator.isSecured.test(request)) {
            if (this.isAuthMissing(request))
                return this.onError(exchange, "Authorization header is missing in request", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            final String token = this.getAuthHeader(request);
            return  webClient.post()
                    .uri(request.getURI().getPath())
                    .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                        httpHeaders.add("Authorization", token);
                        httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    })
                    .retrieve()
                    .onStatus(httpStatus -> httpStatus.is4xxClientError(),
                            response -> Mono.error(new HttpClientErrorException(response.statusCode().toString())))
                    .onStatus(httpStatus -> httpStatus.is5xxServerError(),
                            response -> Mono.error(new HttpClientErrorException(response.statusCode().toString())))

                    .bodyToMono(Void.class)
                    .doOnSuccess(res ->  chain.filter(exchange));

        } else
            return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

    private boolean isAuthMissing(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        return !request.getHeaders().containsKey("Authorization");
    }

    private Mono<Void> onError(ServerWebExchange exchange, String err, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(httpStatus);
        return response.setComplete();
    }

    private String getAuthHeader(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        return request.getHeaders().getOrEmpty("Authorization").get(0);
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class RouterValidator {

    static String[] arr= {"/authenticate"};
    public static final List<String> openApiEndpoints = Arrays.asList(arr);
   

    public Predicate<ServerHttpRequest> isSecured =
            request -> openApiEndpoints
                    .stream()
                    .noneMatch(uri -> request.getURI().getPath().contains(uri));

}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class GatewayConfig {

    @Autowired
    JwtFilter filter;

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("USER-MANAGEMENT", 
                         r -> r.path("/createUser/**")
                         
                        .filters(f -> f.filter(filter))
                        .uri("http://localhost:9092/"))

                .route("AUTH-SERVICE", r -> r.path("/authenticate/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.filter(filter))
                        .uri("http://localhost:9094/"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

What I have Tried?

Answer: I cannot use RestTemplate because Spring Cloud Gateway based on Webflux and RestTemplate will not work.

`.block()` will not work, because I am writing webclient in gateway filter. It will give like:

```
WebClient.block throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread
```

What I am expecting:

- When webclient receives status 200 from AUTH-SERVICE, it should forward the request to USER-SERVICE
- When webclient receives another code, it should return with the status code it received from AUTH-SERVICE